# suppress error message

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When ever I run the below AND there are no .csv files I get an error stating the path is null - which it is as there is nothing there to delete...it does NOT stop the script but I get users thinking there is something wrong as powershell loves to show RED characters and that freaks people out!

How do I let the script run but suppress the error?

CODE:

```
filter removeallcsv([string]$path = '.')
    {
        Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".csv"} | Foreach-Object {$_.fullName}
    }


Remove-Item (removeallcsv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `If` statement:

```
$files = removeallcsv

if ($files) { Remove-Item $files } else {"nothing to delete"}
```

One liner:

```
 if ( ($files=removeallcsv)) { Remove-Item $files } else {"nothing to delete"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially passing $null to `Remove-Item`, try this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.csv'} | Remove-Item
```